# Jquery ajax calls increase exponential on each request

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I use Jquery-ajax calls to post information to a page and display the returned info. The problem I encounter is the following:

When a user makes the first ajax call everything seems normal. When a user does not reload the page and makes the same request for a second time the post-call is made 2 times and the get-call as well. The 3th time there are 4post+4get requests. 4th time 8Post/8Gets. And so on.. until the browser (firefox latest v.) freezes for a while.

I'm a beginning programmer and I don't know what the cause might be. I don't know where to look inside my code. Prehaps you guys can give me a hint. My other ajax requests are fine and only post+get once.

Firebug log:
[image: this is a screenshot from firebug]

This is a piece of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').change(function()
    {
        sendDate($('#datepicker').val());               
    });
});

    function sendDate(str)
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "manage_processor.php",
            data: { chosendate: str },
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#printdiv').html(data);              
            }
        });     
    }
```

Hope anyone can shine some light on this situation.

Comment: are you rebinding the event handler at all?

Comment: Is "manage_processor.php" the same file that generated the Javascript  binding in first place? it look like your "data" contains your Javascript code or file reference.

Comment: Is there any other event handler bound to the datepicker (Somewhere else in your script) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I might venture a guess, I suspect the returned data contains a script tag referencing your javascript file. This would explain the GET request you are seeing. Every time the request data is put into #printdiv your script is loaded again and an identical javascript handler would be bound to the same event. This would explain the number of handlers doubling after every request.

Quick test: put console.log( 'script loaded' ); at the top of manage_functions.js. If I'm right it will log after every request.

Comment: Dear Alex, u are completely right! I loaded the same script on the page which was requested by jquery-ajax. Thanks for this quick and correct answer. peace